# It is Redux an instance of Model-View-ViewModel?

Tags: redux

I seek currently for the Redux core pattern. I have found some very interesting hint and now I wonder if the Model-View-ViewModel pattern could have inspired the Redux library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Redux is primarily inspired by the original Flux Architecture, Elm, and some bits of CQRS / Event Sourcing.  See the [Prior Art](https://redux.js.org/introduction/prior-art) page in the Redux docs for a list of inspirations, as well as the ["Thanks" paragraph in the README](https://redux.js.org/#thanks).

Comment: I am now hearing about MVI (Model View Intent) thrown around in android development. I seems heavily inspired by flux/redux but in a static typed language and for android. Could redux still be considered MVI or at least MVI-like?